# WSO2 EMM Services APK: “INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE”

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

I've a signing and compiled APK but I can not install it on a rooted device.

I've tried: 
- Put APK on system/priv-app folder
- Run adb set-device-owner
- Install apk using adb install

And nothing...

I want to enroll my device with COPE ownership.

Thanks in advance
Martín

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use system service, you might need to sign the system service with system signing key (i.e the key which used to sign the Android OS). In the system service manifest, it set as follows in order to work as a system application

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

However if you need to run this on a rooted device, you can simply remove that attribute from the manifest and make app as a system app using root utility application in order to enroll device with COPE ownership.